Is it possible to create MVC controler on classic web application
I've an WEB application with aspx page (No database, very simple web application). But Now I need to add some API services. I would add controler like when I programm in MVC but is it possible. I try but no success to call my controler, even directly in url
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

<ApiController>
<Route("[Testouille]")>
Public Class LicencingYIController
   Inherits ControllerBase

<HttpGet>
Public Function GetCustomHeader() As ActionResult(Of String)
    Dim customHeader As String = Request.Headers("Custom-Header")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(customHeader) Then
        Return BadRequest("Custom header 'Custom-Header' is missing.")
    Else
        Return Ok("Received custom header: " & customHeader)
    End If
 End Function
End Class

I try from my visual studio https://localhost:myport/Testouille/GetCustomHeader
but nothing pass. I don't enter my GetCustomHeader function (break point)
Then I just ask if is it possible or perhaps finnally better to make an asmx ?
Thanks fot your help.

You've been able to combine Web Forms (which you're erroneously calling "classic web application") with MVC for over a decade. And you don't have to use Web API, though you certain can if it otherwise makes sense.

Finnally ...
U can with web api controler
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class TestouilleController
Inherits ApiController

<HttpGet>
Public Function GetCustomHeader() As IHttpActionResult
    Dim customHeader As String = Request.Headers.GetValues("Custom-Header").FirstOrDefault()

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(customHeader) Then
        Return Content(Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Custom header 'Custom-Header' is missing.")
    Else
        Return Ok("Received custom header: " & customHeader)
    End If
End Function

End Class

I let the header reader... always good to take
Don't forget initialyse the route
Public Class WebApiConfig
Public Shared Sub Register(config As HttpConfiguration)

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="API/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
End Class

To call it in global.asax.start
and Call API, like that
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
 Public Sub GetTesteur()
    Try
        Dim strbrut As String = ""
        Using WC As New WebClient
            WC.Headers.Add("Custom-Header", "Toto")
            strbrut = WC.DownloadString("https://localhost:44367/api/Testouille/GetCustomHeader") 
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

